# FGLRX disturbs TTYs and Plymouth graphics

Tags: 14.04, uefi, fglrx, tty

I just installed Ubuntu Trusty on my new SSD, enabling UEFI, which was disabled previously. After the installation finished (and I finally found a workaround for a strange HP UEFI, which denied booting Ubuntu), I noticed the following problems during Plymouth's animation and when switching to
TTY1-7:

Each screen line is shifted to the right relative to the one above, like you can see in the image below. This results in an ugly boot splash and barely usable (only if I know the commands by heart) TTY.

This only appeared after installing fglrx. Before, when using xserver-xorg-video-ati, everything was fine.

Has anyone experienced this before? How can I fix it?

[image: TTY1]
Image: TTY1 filled with a hexdump

---

Device: HP ProBook 455 G1
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
FGLRX Version: 2:13.350.1-0ubuntu2, installed via Additional Drivers

**EDIT:** Now using FGLRX Version 14.301.1001, installed from ATI installer, problem persists.

**EDIT2:** Video modes listed by `videoinfo` (former called vbeinfo):

```
Adapter `Bochs PCI Video Driver`:
  No info available
Adapter `Cirrus CLGD 5446 PCI Video Driver`:
  No info available
Adapter `EFI GOP driver`:
* 0x000 1366 x  768 x 32 (5464)
  0x001  800 x  600 x 32 (3200)
  0x002 1024 x  768 x 32 (4096)
  0x003  640 x  480 x 32 (2560)
```

**I tried every one of these, the only one that worked was 0x002 1024x768. But how can I enable 1366x768 without the distorted screen?**

---

PS: I previously used Ubuntu on the same computer, but without UEFI and on a HDD. Then it worked, too

Comment: Have you tried using `fglrx-updates` instead?

Comment: a) It's the same version as fglrx in Additional Drivers. b) I'm now using the latest driver from AMD's website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out is is some strange incompatibility with fglrx in HP's UEFI BIOS:

- If I only use Legacy BIOS, the bootsplash is shown correctly
- If I use UEFI BIOS with Legacy support, the bootsplash is always 1024x768, no matter which resolution
- If I only use UEFI BIOS, the screen is distorted, as seen above, except when I choose 1024x768.

Unfortunately, there is no fix for this (except using Xorg's driver) (And I can't even do a BIOS upgrade, because the exact same computer model is needed, but with Windows, to create the upgrade EFI file... VM's don't work)

**Update:** After a BIOS update, the problem does not occur anymore once the fglrx/radeon driver is actually loaded, so by embedding it in the initramfs, the problem can be circumvented easily.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem with FGLRX.

To fix it, you need to edit your boot settings.

In a terminal, run:

```
hwinfo --framebuffer ## Depreciated, use videoinfo instead!
```

It should spit out a lot of numbers. Choose the resolution that you want (usually the highest). Remember the corresponding code!

Now, reboot. In the GRUB menu, edit the entry and add `vga=0x1234` between `quiet` and `splash`, where `0x1234` is the code from above. If it works, then simply open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for the `CMDLINE_DEFAULT`. It should have the same `quiet splash` in it. Now, after `splash`, put the VGA code, like so: `quiet splash vga=0x1234`.

Save and exit from nano and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

<sup>[(src)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMD_Catalyst#Switching_from_X_session_to_TTYs_gives_a_blank_screen.2Flow_resolution_TTY)</sup>

Comment: hwinfo only is avaiable up to Raring...

Comment: I added the information from videoinfo instead. Which of these am I supposed to use?

Comment: It works when I apply `vga=0x002` (1024x768) or set it in `GRUB_GFXMODE`. But how can I get the 1366x768?

Answer (score -2):

Have you to enter this in the terminal or drop shell from recovery:

```
 update-grub 
 update-grub2
 Plymouth-upstart-bridge
 grub-install 
 grub-mkconfig
```

and then enter this from the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: update-grub and update-grub2 is the same. Where's the sense in reinstalling GRUB? And the desktop is the only place whereeverything works fine. Why should I reinstall it?

Comment: It might work because it reinstall the factory configuation.